# Proof partition

Tags: analysis

I got confused with the solution of the following problem:

Proof: For each n ∈ of N, let $A_n = [-n,n]$. Show that $\{A_n : n ∈ N\} $ does not form a partition of R. However, if we define $B_n = [n,n+1)$, then $\{B_n : n ∈ Z\} $ does partition R.

The answer says that $A_n$ doesn't satisfy the partition condition: $ A_1 ∩ A_2 ≠ ø$. The reason: $A_1 ≠ A_2$. But it says that the condition does hold with $B_n ∩ B_m ≠ ø$, arguing $[n,n+1)=[m,m+1)$ then $B_n = B_m$.

My main problem is that I don't understand why we can't use the m, n argument with $A_n$ and why the condition holds if clearly $B_1 ≠ B_2$

Comment: Consider $m=n+1$. This doesn't work with $A_n$. We can't use the $m$,$n$ argument.

Comment: For all $A_n$, we have $0 \in A_n$, thus $\{0\} \subset A_n \cap A_m$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: $A_n\cap A_m=A_{\min\{n,m\}}\neq \emptyset$. So, how can it be a partition ?

Comment: Why is this tagged group-theory?

Answer (score 1):

Because $m\leqslant n\implies A_m\subset A_n\implies A_m\cap A_n=A_m\neq\emptyset$. So, $m\neq n\implies A_m\cap A_n\neq\emptyset$.